# edit input value before saving in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I have a very simple input field for a URL from a user:

```
<%= f.text_field :url, :value=>"#{@url_website}" %>
```

I would like to process the input to check if they put http:// before it, and if not, add it manually. Could I run a function on it before saving? How is this done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you should just put a `before_save` in the model to format the text, so if your model was like this

```
before_save :format_url

def format_url
    #put something important here
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting

```
before_save :adjust_url
```

in the model does the trick.